# Doing regex exec while keeping all variables in block scope

Tags: javascript, regex, ecmascript-6

I am trying to find the shortest, easiest to read, dont repeat yourself, way to do a looped global `exec` while keeping all the variables in the block scope.

I have a string in top level scope:

```
const str = 'AaAa';
```

I now dont want to pollute this top level anymore, and want a short sweet loop to iterate all matches.

I currently do this:

```
const patt = /a/ig;
let match;
while (match = patt.exec(str)) {
   console.log(match);
}
```

This however puts match and patt into the top level scope (assuming i dont wrap it in a block)

This works, but I have to repeat `match=patt.exec(str)` in the initializing part of the `for` and the repeating part of the `for`:

```
for (let patt = /a/ig, match=patt.exec(str); match; match=patt.exec(str)) {
    console.log('match:', match);
}
```

Is there any ideas on how to do this last way, without repeating the `match=patt.exec(str)`? (ideally `patt` would be `const patt` instead of `let patt` as it helps the easy to read by being more delcaritive)

Ideally something like this broken pseudo-code:

```
for (const patt = /a/ig, let match=patt.exec(str); match;) {
    console.log('match:', match);
}
```

Comment: From a readability point of view, how about a closure? https://jsfiddle.net/rkfhe9z8/6/

Comment: Thanks @gurvinder372 - that's a nice idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would just write

```
{
    const patt = /a/ig;
    for (let match; match=patt.exec(str); ) {
        console.log('match:', match);
    }
}
```

You cannot combine a `let` with a `const` statement in a `for` loop head.

You might want to leave off the surrounding block, there should be nothing wrong with having the `const patt` in the same scope as the `const str`.

Comment: Alternately: `for (let patt = /a/ig, match; match = patt.exec(str); ) { console.log(match); }`.

Comment: Very nice! Thank you Bergi, I like @T.J.Crowder method. I was thinking though someone would say something  using generators/iterators . And haha @ TJCrowder I see your funny comment in the deleted post. :)

Comment: Whoa, I just put `patt` into same scope as `str` to test it out. I was hesitating to do this because I had a `g` flag, so it always remembered `lastIndex`. But it seems after the loop completes, `lastIndex` is getting reset to 0. Why is this? Does `lastIndex` get reset after first non-find? I didnt know this reset behavior, which makes it perfectly ok to `g` patt's in global space now!

Comment: @Noitidart Oh sure you can write a generator that could be called like `for (const match of allMatches(/a/ig)) …` or something

Comment: @Noitidart Yes, `lastIndex` is reset to `0` when it does not find another match. But you're not going to use `patt` again anyway, regardless in what scope it is declared? The initialisation of the variable would happen every time the loop is evaluated…

Comment: Ah so maybe I should use `.match` instead of `.exec`. I wonder what the point of `.exec` is then, do you know?

Comment: @Noitidart Afaik `match` and `exec` for non-global regexes are just the same, only having the method on the other side. They differ when called with a global regex - `match` returns an array of all matches, `exec` just the next match.

Comment: Oh yes you are correct especially `match` doesnt support "sub matches" when used with global flag I think.